# What is the benefit of re-exporting modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The last two React projects I worked on have been export defaulting the components/pages. Right next to them in index.js:

```
export { default as Icon } from "../Icon";
```

The people who started the project couldn't give me a proper explanation why.

What are the benefits to this compared to just exporting from the file and then:

```
import { Icon } from '../Icon/Icon';
```

Comment: I don't think there is any as such . It is mostly used for grouping a certain components as one . For example if you have a folder which has components shared across your entire app . you can have one index.js file in this folder and can use it to re-export . So that in the other places of your app you can do `import { a, b, c } from 'shared-components'` instead of `import a from shared-component/a`

Comment: @Shyam and `import b from shared-component/b` and `import c from shared-component/c` ad nauseam. 

Answer (score 2):

I think its to improve the code readability as it removes the need to repeat component name two times. Also lets say we are exporting multiple items from a single component folder. It becomes easier to put them all in a single index.js and import necessary ones in a single line.

```
import C, {C1, C2, C3} from 'components/C'
```